# How to install Facebook Video Caller plugin in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I am using Windows 8.1. When I tried to make a video call on Facebook, I got the instructions to install a video calling plugin. I continued with the installation; it downloads the plugin but the installation is vanishing in the middle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: am using google chrome

Comment: Try Firefox or IE there might be a problem with the Chrome extension

Comment: i tried on firefox too but the pluggin installation will not finish it going frm the middle